# piping and redirection for execv command

Tags: c, pipe, dup2, dup

Why piping doesn't work for the following code?

```
int p_fds[2];
pipe(p_fds);

int pid_left = fork();
if (pid_left == 0){
    dup2(p_fds[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(p_fds[0]);
    close(p_fds[1]);
    execv("cat", (char*[]){ "cat", "afile" });//execlp("cat", "cat", "afile", NULL);         
    exit(1);
}

int pid_right = fork();
if (pid_right == 0){
    dup2(p_fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(p_fds[1]);
    close(p_fds[0]);
    execv("grep", (char*[]){ "grep", "something" });//execlp("grep", "grep", "something", NULL);
    exit(1);
}

close(p_fds[0]);
close(p_fds[1]);
waitpid(pid_left, NULL, 0);
waitpid(pid_right, NULL, 0);
```

but it works with `execlp` or any other exec* except `execv`. What should be updated to make it work with `execv`?
It is expected that this code print something in main stdout like `cat afile | grep sth`.

Comment: Your argument arrays **must** be NULL terminated. This code would benefit from some error checking (`if (fork/execv(...) == -1) { /* uh oh */ }`).

Comment: What is `left` in `execv(left->items[0], left->items);`? And why is this line here if the previous line is expected to replace the process' execution context completely? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Oka `left`and `xecv(left->items[0], left->items)`  is not needed. I removed them. I would add error checking later. Thanks.

Comment: But error checking would help you *now*, as it would quickly reveal why `execv` is failing. One `if (-1 == execv(...)) { perror("..."); /* ... */ }` is an easy way to be pointed towards an answer (hint: `man execv`, and read the difference between `execv` and `execvp`).

Comment: @Oka Thanks. It is really not expected errors for 1st and 2d execv. 
 ...: No such file or directory
...: Permission denied
Because the file exist (in the same dir) and it’s not clear what is wrong with permission

Comment: this statement: `execv("grep", (char*[]){ "grep", "something" });`  should be: `execv("grep", (char*[]){ "grep", "something" , NULL});`  Notice the trailing NULL

Comment: regaarding: `execv("cat", (char*[]){ "cat", "afile" });//execlp("cat", "cat", "afile", NULL);         
    exit(1);`  should be: `execv("/bin/cat", (char*[]){ "cat", "afile", NULL });  perror( "execv failed" );         
    exit(1);

Answer (score 1):

It is needed to provide full path for
`execv(full_path, char *const argv[]);`
execv("/bin/cat")
Other functions (exec*) perforce search in $PATH